# Django don't save choice field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I try save choice field but for no reason field never save. I try create modelform and even in admin panel this field don't save.

I want to give user option to choose when he want to get email recomendations.

Maybe someone have idea whats wrong. I see documentation of django and still don't get why this don't save.

My model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
DAILYDIGEST = 'DAILY'
WEEKLYDIGEST = 'WEEKLY'
NONERECOMMENDATION = 'NONEREC'

EMAILDIGEST = [
    (NONERECOMMENDATION, 'Nie wysyłaj mi rekomendacji'),
    (DAILYDIGEST, 'Dzienne rekomendacje'),
    (WEEKLYDIGEST, 'Cotygodniowe rekomendacje'),
]
[...]
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='Użytkownik')
[...]
emailrecommendation = models.CharField(
    verbose_name='Wybierz jak często chcesz otrzymywać rekomendacje',
    max_length=20,
    choices = EMAILDIGEST,
    default = WEEKLYDIGEST,
)
```

Model form:

```
class EmailRecommendations(ModelForm):

  class Meta:
      model = Profile
      fields = ['emailrecommendation']
```

View:

```
def emailrecsettings(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
      form = EmailRecommendations(instance=request.user.profile, data=request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          formsave = form.save()
          print(formsave)
  else:
      form = EmailRecommendations(instance=request.user.profile)
  return render(request, 'profile/emailrecommendations.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Did you try adding some print statements or logging to your view to better understand what's happening?

Comment: So what's the field value after saving through admin? Don't you have indented your fields and choice list inside the class? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

In your ModelForm class,
define forms.ChoiceField to make choice available in a form field:

```
class EmailRecommendations(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      emailrecommendation = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(), 
                                              choices = Profile.EMAILDIGEST , 
                                              initial='NONERECOMMENDATION', 
                                              required = True,)
      model = Profile
      fields = ['emailrecommendation']
```

or

```
 widgets = {
            'emailrecommendation ' : forms.Select()
        }
```

Another way, we can change it's value dynamically before render.

```
# In request def
def emailrecsettings(request):
   FormInstance = EmailRecommendations()
   FormInstance.fields['emailrecommendation'].choices = Profile.EMAILDIGEST,
   FormInstance.fields['emailrecommendation'].initial = 'NONERECOMMENDATION'
```

Comment: Thank You for response. Sadly still don't work. i try change model form with Your example and still form don't save.